# Shell alias to start two processes

Tags: multithreading, bash, shell, alias, zsh

I have been forced to work with a piece of Windows desktop software, so I run it under Wine. I want an alias for my zshrc that will run `Xquartz` and `wine /path/to/file.exe` in one go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought that X launched automatically if you just leave the DISPLAY at the default
on my machine I see:

```
$ echo $DISPLAY 
/tmp/launch-WdPl5u/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
```

---

That aside ...

I never used wine (so I don't know if wine is installed as a Mac App or just an executable), So I am Not sure which is a better way

```
function wineThis()
{
    open -a /Applications/Utilities/XQuartz.app
    open -a PATH_TO_WINE.app ${1}
}
```

or

```
function wineThis()
{
    /Applications/Utilities/XQuartz.app/Contents/MacOS/X11.bin &
    disown
    wine ${1}  &
    disown
}
```

In both cases you should be able to do
`wineThis /path/to/file.exe`
in an alias or commandline

I think the `disown`s are optional, and should allow you to exit the bash shell

p.s. You could also do a hybrid (use `open` to launch X, then run wine in background (`&`) and disown)

Comment: Pretty sure this is all due to an Xquartz update breaking something, but the hybrid approach worked. Thanks!

Comment: @odonnell Did you reboot after the Xquartz update?  I think a reboot will fix the auto-launch of X

Comment: Yup. I think it's a problem with Wine, it's isolated to this one situation.